# Composer vs component manger vs manual install

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer, setup

Trying to see which method is the best to install extensions by. I would always lean towards composer however it looks as though many articles online would suggest using Magento's Component manager is the best way.

Is there any advantages of using the Magento's Component manager over composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento's Web Setup Wizard is essentially a GUI wrapper for the Marketplace composer repo--it's running composer processes internally. If you are comfortable with composer, you can do all of the same things from the command line without any issues.

Most guides and extension directions are written to users who don't necessarily know their way around the command line, so they'll tend to use the web UI.

If a given package or extension is available from composer, always prefer that over a manual code upload/install.

Comment: Thanks, somehow hit down vote when I meant to click up. It wont let me change my vote though